# Kendo Grid inline editing with custom editor doesn't bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to make simple combo box inline editor. I managed to make create new row working by putting stupid workaround on kendoComboBox change, but update still isn't working (unless you change field with default editor) and also combo box doesn't show selected value.

Grid:

```
$("#pseudo-category-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            // CRUD stuff..
        },
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total",
            errors: "Errors",
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    PseudoCategory: {editable: true, type: "string" },
                    PseudoCategoryId: {editable: true, type: "number" },
                    DisplayOrder2: {editable: true, type: "number" },
                    IncludeAllChildren: {editable: true, type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        },
        requestEnd: function(e) {
            if(e.type=="update") {
                this.read();
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
            this.cancelChanges();
        },
        pageSize: @(defaultGridPageSize),
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    },
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: [@(gridPageSizes)]
    },
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "@T("Admin.Common.AddNewRecord")" }],
    editable: {
        confirmation: false,
        mode: "inline"
    },
    scrollable: false,
    columns: [{
        field: "PseudoCategoryId",
        title: "Pseudo Category",
        editor: pseudoCategoryDropDownEditor,
        template: "#:PseudoCategory#"
    // other unrelated fields removed...
    }, {
        command: [{
            name: "edit",
            text: {
                edit: "@T("Admin.Common.Edit")",
                update: "@T("Admin.Common.Update")",
                cancel: "@T("Admin.Common.Cancel")"
            }
        }, {
            name: "destroy",
            text: "@T("Admin.Common.Delete")"
        }],
        width: 200
    }]
});
```

Custom editor:

```
function pseudoCategoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("PseudoCategoryList", "Category"))',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: addAntiForgeryToken(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('<input required data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="value:PseudoCategoryId"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoComboBox({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataSource: data.Data,
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    dataValueField: "Id",
                    filter: "contains",
                    change: function(e) {
                        var value = this.value();
                        options.model.PseudoCategoryId = value;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
                            if (value == data.Data[i].Id)
                                options.model.PseudoCategory = data.Data[i].Name;
                        }
                    }
                });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Failed to get pseudo categories');
        }
    });
}
```

Call to `@Html.Raw(Url.Action("PseudoCategoryList", "Category"))` simply returns array of Ids and Names in Data field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by [manually binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-bind) combo box to model:

```
function pseudoCategoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("PseudoCategoryList", "Category"))',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: addAntiForgeryToken(),
        success: function (data) {
            var elem = $('<input required data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="value:PseudoCategoryId"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoComboBox({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataSource: data.Data,
                    filter: "contains"
                });
            if (options.model.PseudoCategoryId == 0)
                options.model.PseudoCategoryId = data.Data[0].Id;
            kendo.bind(elem, options.model);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Failed to get pseudo categories');
        }
    });
}
```